# Voicemail using Twilio and Android

Tags: android, twilio

I have to implement the functionality of voicemail using Twilio. Is it possible to implement the voicemail functionality using Twilio? Our Twilio call is working properly but now we don't have any idea about how to implement the voicemail functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You absolutely can use Twilio to implement voicemail. You'll want to look into using the TwiML verb [`<Record>` which records messages from the person on the phone](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/record).

It might be best to check out this tutorial on [phone screening and voicemail with Twilio Voice](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/ivr-screening/java/servlets), it might give you an idea how to update your existing Twilio setup.

Let me know if this helps at all.

Comment: I have a doubt regarding voice mail: suppose I am making a call(MO) to you(MT) and you are not answering the call in this case how can I come to know to redirect call on voice mail.

Comment: Hi @AjitKumarDubey, not sure what you mean here. What do you mean by MO and MT? Which part of this call you are talking about is the Twilio part?

Comment: Yes @philnash's i am talking about twilio. MO is mobile orginator and MT is mobile terminator.

Comment: I wanted to implement voice mail when mobile terminator is not answering call of mobile orginator

Comment: When you are using the `<Dial>` TwiML verb, you can set a [`timeout`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial#attributes-timeout). When the timeout fires, the [`action`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial#attributes-action) URL will get called, at which point you can respond with more TwiML using [`<Record>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/record) to record a message. Does that help?